# How can I get from Kashan to Yazd, Iran?

Tags: public-transport, taxis, iran

I'm planning a trip to Iran and I can't find bus transportation from Kashan to Yazd. Is that correct? If so, is there any other way to get there?

I have read that taxi drivers sometimes offer transportation between  cities in Iran. Is it possible to do Kashan-Yazd by taxi? How much should I expect it to cost?

Comment: From Qom to Kashan, or from Kashan to Yazd?

Comment: What about going by train? You can go from Kashan to Yazd by train which costs around 5 to 9 USD. It seems though that there is no train going from Qom to Yazd.

Comment: @Meysam Sorry for the confusion is from Kashan to Yazd,  do you know where can I find the information about the train and how easy is to buy the tickets in Iran?

Comment: There are many sites where you can buy tickets online but most of them are in Persian. I guess you should usually be able to buy ticket in the train station before boarding.

Comment: @Meysam yeah Persian doesn't work at all, but are the time tables available somewehere I found this page : http://iranrail.netwhich is the UNOFFICIAL and it list 4 different types of trains Luxe, Pardis trainset, Alboz  and Ghazal do you know whats the difference between the 4 of them and if that page is to be trusted?

Comment: I could find this for you: https://www.travelenter.com/En/Home/Index#train-tab give it a try and see if it works for you. Select your date and see the available trains.

Comment: It seems like the same I found in iranrail.net Thanks

Comment: Yea http://iranrail.net seems fine and you can trust it. Luxe, Pardis and Ghazal are different in the quality of service you receive. It seems that Ghazal is the best one among them :)

Comment: @Meysam make sense but ill book it depending on the time it departs. Thanks again

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask for help here should you get into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I checked most of online bus reservation websites and it seems there's no direct bus to Yazd. you can travel to `Isfahan` and the get a bus to `Yazd`.

It can be a good idea since there's plenty of available bus in this way.

Comment: I manage to find that, and its exactly what i want to avoid

Comment: @Alejandro Andrade, I know It can be a little hard to have such long trip with an extra stop. Actually I live in Isfahan and I can help you in my city. we can find a suitable bus to Yazd.

Comment: thanks for the proposal, I´m actually going to isfahan but i plan the rout as kashan-yazd-shiraz-isfahan thats why I don´t want the bus to isfaha. But as Meysam comment theres the train and it seems to work for me